# Click event and namespaced click event - which fires first and will stopPropagation() cancel one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Example: foundation dropdown has namespaced event `click.fndtn.dropdown`.
Their code binds to it, but not to pure `click`.

What happens when I bind to `click` event of same element?

1. Which event fires first?
2. If I call `event.stopPropagation()` in `click` handler will that cancel `click.fndtn.dropdown` handler?
3. If I call `event.stopPropagation()` in `click.fndtn.dropdown` handler will that cancel `click` handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Which even fires first?

jQuery ensures that they're fired in the order in which they were attached (which is also standard now, as of a few years ago).

> 2. If I call `event.stopPropagation()` in `click` handler will that cancel `click.fndtn.dropdown` handler?

No, but [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) will **if** your handler was registered first.

> 3. If I call `event.stopPropagation()` in `click.fndtn.dropdown` handler will that cancel click handler?

No, but `stopImmediatePropagation` will **if** that handler was registered first.

Example:

```js
$("#ns-first-stop-prop").on("click.ns", function(e) {
  console.log("click.ns -- calling stopPropagation");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#ns-first-stop-prop").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("click -- calling stopPropagation");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#plain-first-stop-prop").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("click -- calling stopPropagation");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#plain-first-stop-prop").on("click.ns", function(e) {
  console.log("click.ns -- calling stopPropagation");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#ns-first-stop-immed").on("click.ns", function(e) {
  console.log("click.ns -- calling stopImmediatePropagation");
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$("#ns-first-stop-immed").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("click -- calling stopImmediatePropagation");
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$("#plain-first-stop-immed").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("click -- calling stopImmediatePropagation");
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$("#plain-first-stop-immed").on("click.ns", function(e) {
  console.log("click.ns -- calling stopImmediatePropagation");
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```html
<div><input type="button" id="ns-first-stop-prop" value="Namespaced First - calls stopPropagation"></div>
<div><input type="button" id="plain-first-stop-prop" value="Non-Namespaced First - calls stopPropagation"></div>
<div><input type="button" id="ns-first-stop-immed" value="Namespaced First - calls stopImmediatePropagation"></div>
<div><input type="button" id="plain-first-stop-immed" value="Non-Namespaced First - calls stopImmediatePropagation"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So only difference is that calling `off` on namespaced click will not unbind click? And will calling `off` on `click`  unbind namespaced click?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš: Calling `off("click.namespaced"...` will only unhook those namespaced handlers. Calling `off("click", ...` removes *all* `click` handlers that were attached with jQuery, including namespaced ones.